# How to find the xpath for the link given below?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

Please help me find the xpath for the page https://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

In this page there is a para "Selenium Standalone Server". In that I have to find the xpath for Download version link "3.141.59". Since it is a number I cannot use this number to find as it's dynamic and it may change in near future. Please help me with this.

[image]

Comment: Welcome: have a look at [how to ask](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/asking). You might get downvotes for not [trying](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) yourself first. What did you research, what did you try? It looks like a homework question...

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the DOM?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the surrounding context which (presumably) will not change and search for the link within that context regardless of the contents of the link.

**One way of doing that:**

```
//h3[text()='Selenium Standalone Server']/following-sibling::p[contains(text(),'Download version')][1]/a
```

**Explanation of the above xpath:**

We want the link within the `Selenium Standalone Server` section:

```
//h3[text()='Selenium Standalone Server']
```

We see the paragraph we are looking for is on the same level as the `h3` title, so we use the `following-sibling` axis:

```
 //h3[text()='Selenium Standalone Server']/following-sibling::p
```

This returns many elements, we only want the one with our link which we identify by the `Download version` text:

```
//h3[text()='Selenium Standalone Server']/following-sibling::p[contains(text(),'Download version')]
```

We are only interested in the first one:

```
//h3[text()='Selenium Standalone Server']/following-sibling::p[contains(text(),'Download version')][1]
```

And we are looking for the link within that paragraph, which is our final xpath:

```
//h3[text()='Selenium Standalone Server']/following-sibling::p[contains(text(),'Download version')][1]/a
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This xPath should work perfectly:

```
//p[normalize-space(text())="Download version"]/a
```

Basically, it can be simplified to

```
//p[text()="Download version "]/a
```